# Understanding Fourier Transform Theorem in Folland: Theorem 8.35

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, proof-explanation, fourier-transform

While reading Folland's Real Analysis textbook, I came across the Fourier Analysis section and became troubled by Theorem 8.35.  It goes as follows:

[image]

[image]

Focusing on part $a.$ of the theorem, I am confused about the sudden change of supposition where we originally considered $f \in L^1 + L^2$, but then in $a.$ suddenly consider $f \in L^p \, (1 \leq p < \infty)$.  In particular, I have not seen any mention of the Fourier transform if $f \in L^p$ for $p > 2$ (could we use Schwartz functions?).  Furthermore as he begins the proof he lets $f = f_1 + f_2$ where $f_1 \in L^1$ and $f_2 \in L^2$, which to me signifies that he is still using $f \in L^1 + L^2$.  The proof of $a.$ makes sense to me, but only for $f \in L^1 + L^2$, how are we suddenly also considering $f \in L^p \, (1 \leq p < \infty)$?

Comment: I think the assumption that $f \in L^1 + L^2$ applies throughout. In part a, $f \in L^p$ is an additional assumption.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what was throwing me off.  I thought Folland was throwing out that assumption.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f=f_1+f_2$ and $f_j\in L^j,$ then we know that $\hat{f_1}\in L^\infty$ and $\hat{f_2}\in L^2$ by the mapping properties of the Fourier transform. In the second sentence of the statement of the theorem, they assume that $f\in L^1+L^2,$ so such a decomposition is perfectly kosher. They assumed that $f\in L^p$ in part (a) to use theorem 8.14.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the mentioned mapping property.  I suppose my difficulty is if $f \in L^p$ for $p > 2$, then what exactly is $f^t$ as is defined in the theorem?  In particular, what is the $\widehat{f}(\xi)$ term in $f^t$?

Comment: The Fourier transform is linear, so it makes perfect sense to take the Fourier transform of $f_1+f_2$ (which equals $f$). The $L^p$ assumption isn't used to take the Fourier transform.

Comment: If you like, $f\in (L^1+L^2)\cap L^p$ in part a.

Comment: Oh gosh, I get it!  I understand what you're saying and understand about the linearity principal.  I was assuming we disregarded that $f \in L^1 + L^2$ when we said $f \in L^p$.  Thank you.

Comment: Happens to everyone sometimes :)